# How can I use CAS registration on my web app?

Tags: php, cas

My school has a CAS system that handle all the college student login activity. I am building a webapp that will go to one of the school website that has all the deadlines information of homework, and download those deadlines for me. However, in order to do so, I will need to first login with CAS then go to the website and get things. I am wondering how can I use my school's cas login for my own webapp?

Here is my idea so far:

my website --> redirect to my school's cas page ----> somehow cas page will return some credentials to my website ----> with that credentials  my website can go to another school's website and download stuffs.

I am not sure if my idea is right and I do not know how to get credential from cas page either.  I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: it's the right general idea, but without any details about your school's cas, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to declare your web app in the CAS services management (you need some admin role here). Therefore, you will benefit from the regular CAS authentication process.
Then, if you want to get "stuffs" from another web app and use your first web app as a CAS proxy, you will need to setup the appropriate configuration. Take a look at : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough to see if it matches your need.